# swift 3 CGPathAddCurveToPoint

Tags: swift3, cgpath

I'm trying to update code to swift 3 but I can't find anything about CGPathAddCurveToPoint, how can I fix the error?

path is a CGMutablePath

```
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, nil, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30)
```

error: nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UnsafePoiter'

I found that CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 10, 10)
became path.addLine(to: p0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the CGMutablePath docs:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgmutablepath

You will find:

```
func addCurve(to end: CGPoint, control1: CGPoint, control2: CGPoint, 
    transform: CGAffineTransform = default)
```

Note that this is now a *method*, not a loose global function.