# convert CGPathAddArcToPoint to Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, core-graphics, cgpath

I upgraded to Swift 3 and I'm having an impossible time finding tips online to fix this. I was able to research move and add a line but not this one.

```
CGPathAddArcToPoint(bubblePath, nil,
    bubbleRect.origin.x+bubbleRect.size.width, bubbleRect.origin.y, 
    bubbleRect.origin.x+bubbleRect.size.width, bubbleRect.origin.y+self.cornerRadius,
    self.cornerRadius)
```

Here is my original code but I have no idea how to convert it. I'm pretty sure I need to use addArc but that is the extent of my research.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is now a method and not a loose global function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgmutablepath/2427124-addarc) [(as quoted in this related question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554110/swift-3-cgpathaddcurvetopoint), so the way you'd need to do this should be something like:

```
let bubblePath = CGMutablePath.init()
let point1 = CGPoint(x: bubbleRect.origin.x+bubbleRect.size.width, y: bubbleRect.origin.y)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: bubbleRect.origin.x+bubbleRect.size.width, y: bubbleRect.origin.y+self.cornerRadius) 
bubblePath.addArc(tangent1End: point1, tangent2End: point2, radius: self.cornerRadius)
```

Comment: `bubblePath` is probably already in place so the first line may not be needed.

Comment: Thank you so much i appreciate your help. I will fix this right now.

Answer (score 1):

The Swift (3 and later) replacement for that one is [`addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgmutablepath/2427124-addarc).

You can use it like this (also using some other handy Swift API on `CGRect` to be concise):

```
bubblePath.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: bubbleRect.maxX, y: bubbleRect.minY)
                  tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bubbleRect.maxX, y: bubbleRect.minY + self.cornerRadius),
                  radius: self.cornerRadius)
```

(Note the `transform` parameter has a default value of `.identity`, so you can leave it off in cases where you'd have used `nil` with the global-function version.)

Comment: Thank you so much, i will add this ASAP. Much appreciated.